# iOS 8 - UIAlertController button styling not being applied correctly

Tags: ios, ios8, dialog, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I have a UIAlertController with 2 UIAlertAction buttons that I've added -- one labeled "OK" and the other labeled "Cancel".  I'm using UIAlertActionStyle.Default styling for both of them.  However, the Cancel button seems to have the .Cancel styling (strong font weight) applied to it and that is not what I'm looking for. How do I get rid of that styling?

Note: I noticed that if I change the order in which the UIAlertAction buttons are added to the UIAlertController -- "Cancel" button added first followed by the "OK" button -- then the "OK" button gets the strong font weight instead.

Answer (score 3):

In short, iOS 8 won't allow you to have no bold text buttons on an alert.

iOS is going to bold what it assumes is the default option. Because the user interface guidelines call for putting the most often-desired option on the right, and the order buttons are added determines the order they are displayed on two button alerts, the second option added is bold. Setting the UIAlertActionStyle to cancel vs default doesn't make a noticeable effect with two buttons.

The user interface guidelines can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Alerts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1). The portion I referenced states:

> Place buttons appropriately. Ideally, the button that's most natural
>   to tap should meet two criteria: It should perform the action that
>   users are most likely to want and it should be the least likely to
>   cause problems if a user taps it inadvertently.Specifically:
>
> When the most likely button performs a nondestructive action, it
>   should be on the right in a two-button alert. The button that cancels
>   this action should be on the left.
>
> When the most likely button performs a destructive action, it should
>   be on the left in a two-button alert. The button that cancels this
>   action should be on the right.

Comment: Currently I have two buttons on my alert, one is "Delete" with style destruction and the other is "Cancel" with style cancel. My understanding was the same as yours, that destructive actions always go on the left. However, no matter which order I add these two buttons, "Delete" is always showing up on the right, styled as red. Cancel is always showing on the left, automatically styled as blue and bold. So what's going on!?

Answer (score 0):

This is some very late answer but I posted this, in case, someone finds it handy, in future.

It seems like even in iOS 9.3, Destructive button has some internal precedence over Cancel button. So for a `UIAlertController` with one Destructive and one Cancel button, the Destructive button always shows on the right.

To overcome this I have changed the Cancel button style to `UIAlertActionStyleDefault` and has set its `preferredAction` to button 1 (the Default button) so that it looks like an original Cancel button.

The code is something like this:

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Are you sure that you want to delete selected picture(s)?" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Yes" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
    //delete
    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}]];
[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"No" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}]];
alert.preferredAction = alert.actions[1];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

And somehow it works, as expected!

PS: The code is in Objective C but can easily be converted to Swift, I guess.